# I want to change the border colour of TouchableOpacity when onPress

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I create a touchable opacity and give it a border style. So i want that when i touch a particular Touchable border it changes its border colour. How can i do that. Thanks

[this is the deafult border style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lbGr.jpg)

[and this is what i want after pressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX1FW.png)

Comment: You want the border to be visible when the user presses the component or when the user taps and holds that component?

Comment: No i want the border change its colour when user tap. Like visible colour of border  is grey but when user select or tap on that particular it change its colour. You can also check the image i give to know what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component that takes in a prop, let's say `isSelected` and based on this you can show the color of the border.

So, your conditional styles would look something like this -

```js
const containerStyles = {
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: isSelected ? 'dodgerblue' : 'grey',
};
```

Now, the usage is simple, you just pass a boolean value while calling is component as shown below

```js
<VehicleButton />
<VehicleButton isSelected={true} />
<VehicleButton />
```

Here's a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/vehicle-button) that has the implementation.